# Creating a timed loop inside Discord Bot script to reload web page (web scraper bot)

Tags: python, time, discord, discord.py, code-structure

I'm currently designing a discord bot that scrapes a web page that is constantly updating for patches related to a PBE server.  I have the bot running through Heroku successfully right now.  The issue I'm running into is I want to create an automated (timed loop) refresh that will reload the website I have requested. As it currently stands, it only loads one instance of the website and if that website changes/updates, none of my content will update as I'm using the "old" request of the website.

Is there a way for me to bury code inside a function so that I can create a timed loop or do I only need to create one around my website request?  How would that look? Thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

# what I want the commands to start with
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

# instantiating discord client
token = "************************************"
client = discord.Client()

# begin the scraping of passed in web page
URL = "*********************************"
page = urlopen(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
pbe_titles = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class': 'news-title'})  # using soup to find all header tags with the news-title
                                                                 # class and storing them in pbe_titles
linksAndTitles = []
counter = 0

# finding tags that start with 'a' as in a href and appending those titles/links
for tag in pbe_titles:
    for anchor in tag.find_all('a'):
        linksAndTitles.append(tag.text.strip())
        linksAndTitles.append(anchor['href'])

# counts number of lines stored inside linksAndTitles list
for i in linksAndTitles:
    counter = counter + 1
print(counter)

# separates list by line so that it looks nice when printing
allPatches = '\n'.join(str(line) for line in linksAndTitles[:counter])
# stores the first two lines in list which is the current pbe patch title and link
currPatch = '\n'.join(str(line) for line in linksAndTitles[:2])


# command that allows user to type in exactly what patch they want to see information for based off date
@bot.command(name='patch')
async def pbe_patch(ctx, *, arg):
    if any(item.startswith(arg) for item in linksAndTitles):
        await ctx.send(arg + " exists!")
    else:
        await ctx.send('The date you entered: ' + '"' + arg + '"' + ' does not have a patch associated with it or that patch expired.')


# command that displays the current, most up to date, patch
@bot.command(name='current')
async def current_patch(ctx):
    response = currPatch
    await ctx.send(response)


bot.run(token)
```

I've played around with

```
while True:
```

loops but whenever I nest anything inside of them, I can't access the code in other places.

Comment: using `while True:` it totally wrong idea. `discord` has object `task` which you can run with timer to repeat task every few minuts. Eventually I would use system service `cron` to run periodically separated script which gets data from page and save in local file and `discord` should read from this file.

Comment: So this would be the ideal convention for creating this bot, yes?  The reading from file?

Comment: BTW: if you created `bot`  -  `commands.Bot(...)` - then you don't need `client` - `discord.Client()` . `bot` is special type of `client`

Comment: shorter `counter = len(linksAndTitles)`

Comment: you could keep title and link as single element ie. as list `linksAndTitles.append( [tag.text.strip(), linksAndTitles.append(anchor['href'])] )` or dictionary `linksAndTitles.append( {"title": tag.text.strip(), "link":  linksAndTitles.append(anchor['href'])} )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`discord` has special decorator `tasks` to run some code periodically

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def scrape(): 
    # ... your scraping code ...


# ... your commands ...


scrape.start()
bot.run(token)
```

and it will repeate function `scrape` every 5 seconds.

---

Documentation: [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)

---

On Linux eventually I would use standard service `cron` to run periodically some script. This script could scrape data and save in file or database and `discord` could read from this file or database. But `cron` check tasks every 1 minute so it can't run task more often.

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code.

I use page http://books.toscrape.com created for scrape learning.

I changed few elements. There is no need to create `client` when there is `bot` because `bot` is special kind of `client`

I keep `title` and `link` as dictionary

```
            {
                'title': tag.text.strip(),
                'link': url + anchor['href'],
            }
```

so later it is easier to create text like

```
title: A Light in the ...
link: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html
```

---

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

# default value at start (before `scrape` will assign new value)
# because some function may try to use these variables before `scrape` will create them
links_and_titles = []   # PEP8: `lower_case_namese`
counter = 0
items = []

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def scrape():
    global links_and_titles
    global counter
    global items

    url = "http://books.toscrape.com/"
    page = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    #pbe_titles = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class': 'news-title'})  
    pbe_titles = soup.find_all('h3')  

    # remove previous content
    links_and_titles = []

    for tag in pbe_titles:
        for anchor in tag.find_all('a'):
            links_and_titles.append({
                'title': tag.text.strip(),
                'link': url + anchor['href'],
            })

    counter = len(links_and_titles)
    print('counter:', counter)
    items = [f"title: {x['title']}\nlink: {x['link']}" for x in links_and_titles]

@bot.command(name='patch')
async def pbe_patch(ctx, *, arg=None):
    if arg is None:
        await ctx.send('Use: !patch date')
    elif any(item['title'].startswith(arg) for item in links_and_titles):        
        await ctx.send(arg + " exists!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'The date you entered: "{arg}" does not have a patch associated with it or that patch expired.')

@bot.command(name='current')
async def current_patch(ctx, *, number=1):
    if items:
        responses = items[:number]
        text = '\n----\n'.join(responses)
        await ctx.send(text)
    else:
        await ctx.send('no patches')

scrape.start()

token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
bot.run(token)
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: So if my scraping code is inside a function, can I just call the function after the scrape()?

Comment: if code will be inside  `scrape()` then `@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)` will run it automatically every 5 seconds. But you still may run it manually using `scrape()`. ie. you can run it at start to get first value.

Comment: So i created a function called `scrape_and_store` which has all the code above that finds the url, parses it with BS, then stores that information in a list and returns the list.  Then, when i put that function into the loop, it still won't update.  The bot runs fine, no errors-- It just doesn't seem to constantly pull the webpage over and over. (I'm testing it on my own html and updating the html to see if the commands trigger any changes)

Comment: you don't put in your loop - use `@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)` and it should run it automatically every 5 seconds. And using `return` is useless - because when `task.loop` will run it then it will not now what to do with returned values. You have to assign results to `global` variables.

Comment: I forgot to add `scrape.start()`. It is in code now. You can see `.start()` also in documentation.

Comment: so the loop will hold all the scraping code thats scrapes and stores everything in a list but won't return anything.  Then how do I make sure that I can use that list in my bot commands so I actually return information rather than just returning an empty list?  What does that syntax look like? because I did: `global titles` and then `titles = []` and then inside the `scrape()` command I used `titles` to append what I was scraping, however, I wasn't actually storing any information in the `titles` list as I printed it and it returned `[]` as the output.

Comment: Oh, I simply just did `global titles` and `titles = []` inside the scrape function and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: yes. all variables created outside functions are global variables and you have to use `global titles` inside function to inform it that you want assign value to global `titles` instead of creating local `titles`

Comment: I added full working code which scrapes from page  http://books.toscrape.com - special page for scrape learning.

Comment: I do have one final question: so the problem I'm running into is that I have the scraping code inside the loop, however, I can't put the append stuff inside the loop as it will just constantly add stuff to it including duplicates.  How can I run the loop starting with `for tag in pbe_titles` outside of the function using global variables? Or does it make sense to write an if statement that says only append if there is a new thing (i.e. no duplicates?) how would that look? Very new to python, sorry for the trivial questions.

Comment: if you would run outside `tasks.loop` then you would need another `loop` to run it periodically and you would have to use another `tasks.loop` for this because you can't do this with `while True` - and this makes no sense. Do all inside current `tasks.loop`. You can remove previous content using simply `linksAndTitles = []` before `for`-loop. Eventually you can use some `if/else` to check if element exists in list.

Comment: So I ran your code and it doesn't seem to have that issue.  You're appending items on a 5 second interval inside the loop, how is it not creating duplicates inside your code?  Would it make sense to have the append outside the scrape() loop function or would it make sense to just reset the list every single time it goes and fetches that data? Would this cause latency issues? Such as someone inputting a command and then there being a 4 second delay before the command goes through depending on what point the loop was in? If that makes sense

Comment: I use `linksAndTitles = []` before `for`-loop - and this removes previous elements. I think it can be faster to remove all elements and `append()` again the same elements then comparing elements to see if it exists. Besides this way I also remove items which don't exists on page any more - so I have only elements which exists on page.

Comment: I just did this and tested it on my own HTML and didn't experience any delay.  Thank you so much for the replies.

Comment: so now you can mark my answer as accepted. And few minutes later you can upvote it.

Comment: Yes, sorry new to Stack haha.  Thank you.